# Unable to start training my GCP AutoML Entity Extraction model on Web UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, entity, extract, google-cloud-automl

I am trying to train my first GCP AutoML Entity Extraction model using AutoML Web UI.

I loaded and annotated 74 PDFs (6-pages PDF) with 9 labels (see [Screenshot of GCP AutoML Entity Extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idBKt.png)). It seems that I respected the 10 annotations minimum for both train, validation and test sets. Nevertheless, I am unable to click on Start Training (greyed-out button on Web UI). No indication is given by the GCP AutoML Web UI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the dataset is located in European Union.

Comment: Hi Did you make sure you have sufficient permission? may be try enabling AutoML API.

Comment: Yes, Cloud AutoML API is enabled. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I chatted with support and this is a "known issue" - the minimum number of "Training items per label" is 100. Yes, it would be useful if this was reflected in the UI, and they know this.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/quotas#limits

Comment: Strangely I finally completed the training thanks to the Python API using the European endpoint as mentioned in the [AutoML documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/locations) . I did not meet the minimum of 100 training items per label as you can see in the screenshot.
I supposed that the UI do not let the user to change the endpoint for resources stored in the European Union location.