# In Google Cloud Platform «Start training» is disable

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I am training a model in GCP's AutoML Natural Language Entity extraction.

I have 50+ annotations for each label but still cant start training a model.
Take a look at a screenshot of the
[train section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpkPV.png). The Start training button remains grey and cannot be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot it seems as if you may be talking about training an AutoML Entity Extraction model. Then, this issue seems the same as in [Unable to start training my GCP AutoML Entity Extraction model on Web UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473668/unable-to-start-training-my-gcp-automl-entity-extraction-model-on-web-ui)

There are thus a couple of reasons that may result in this behavior:

- Your dataset are located in a specific region (e.g. "EU") and you need to specify the proper endpoint, as shown in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/locations#setting_the_location_using_client_libraries).
- You might need to increase the number of "Training items per label" to 100 at minimum (see [Natural Language limits](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/quotas#limits)).

From the aforementioned post, the solution seems to be the first one.

Comment: Moving forward, remember to accept an answer if it was helpful so members of the community are able to find it sooner should they experience the same issue as you did.